# Any+Time: i18N of day and month abbreviations from moment.js

Tags: jquery, internationalization, momentjs, anytime

I'm using the time / date picker [Any+Time](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) (jQuery-Plug-In). Additionally [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for time manipulation.
Instead of moment.js the Any+Time plug-in does not support different languages directly.

For moment.js there additional files to [support other languages](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/abbreviations) including the abbreviations of months and days. So I want them to reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting the language globally in moment.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/moment.min.de.js"></script>
<script>
     moment.lang("de");
</script>
```

I an instance of an moment object to gather the abbreviations while initializing the datepicker:

```
<script>
    var $moment = moment();
    $('.datepicker').AnyTime_picker({ 
        format: "%a %d.%m.%Y",
        dayAbbreviations: $moment.lang()._weekdaysShort,
        monthAbbreviations: $moment.lang()._monthsShort
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Nice reuse, but I think you are looking for `moment.langData()._weekdaysShort` and `moment.langData()._monthsShort`. You could also pass the locale code as a parameter instead of using it globally. `moment.langData('de')...`.  (No `$` before moment either)

Comment: That's in the latest 2.1.0.  Technically, we are talking about using private fields, so it's not in the docs and there's no guarantee this API won't break.  Your code may have been correct for an earlier version.